# Where is My files actual data http content-disposition?

Tags: html, http, content-disposition

I am trying to understand how downloads are sent to the clients browser using reverse engineering of code.

What I have so far discovered is that HTTP headers play a large role particularly in reference to the `Content-Disposition` tag / line. For example, I have found out that the following code sets up a download for a txt file named TEST1234, and that it is downloaded as an attachment as apposed to an inline.

```
HTTP/1.x 200 OK
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" ,"TEST1234.txt
```

However I was expecting that the code would also hold the files actual contents with in the rest of the http or at least the ajoining HTML code?

What leads me to think this is because some PHP codes are as follows...

```
<?php
  $filename="download.txt";
  header("Content-disposition: attachment;filename=$filename");
  readfile($filename);
?>
```

I am not at all familiar with PHP but can make out enough to see that the line `readfile($filename);` probably reads the file (server end) into a stream and adds the files coding it to either the HTTP header or the adjoining HTML that is posted as response to the client? Upon receiving the response, the clients browser knows that the file should be saved as "download".txt. Assuming that download.txt contained the text `Hello world`, I would think the sent response would look as follows?

```
    HTTP/1.x 200 OK
    Content-Type: application/octet-stream
    Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" ,"download.txt"

    <html>Hello world</html>
```

Comment: Whatever tool you're using may just be hiding anything that's believed to be binary (aka `application/octet-stream`). You may want to try plain text or a different tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution...

I had simply not created a blank line between the HTTP header and the HTML.... or in this case the file contents...

```
                .Append("HTTP/1.1 200 OK" & Environment.NewLine)
                .Append("Content-Type: text/plain" & Environment.NewLine)
                .Append("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" & Chr(34) & "TEST.txt" & Chr(34) & Environment.NewLine)
                .Append(Environment.NewLine)    <--------------- THIS LINE NOW WORKS
                .Append("Hello world!")
```

Although is there an way to encode web freindly/ safe encode the contents which the browser knows how to decode back to its original contents... simular to base64 encoding?

Comment: What does this code have to do with the question? This is not PHP code and this is not how PHP works. `header()` queues headers to a separate channel and anything you sent to standard output (e.g. `readfile()`) triggers proper headers as needed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, note I was not ever intrested in PHP quite the contrast, I simply noted that the PHP example showed the structure of a download HTTP/ HTML and if I had actually observed it correctly seeing as in VB.net I wasn't getting the expected result. ONCE MORE the answer to the whole riddle was that there needs to be a empty line between the HTTP header and the adjoining HTML for anything to take effect (case solved).

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is "yes, it does look like that" - assuming that the content of the file is literally `<html>Hello world</html>`. If it's just `Hello world`, then that's literally what the response will contain - there's no "adjoining HTML", it's just that responding with HTML is a common *use* of HTTP.

As you'll see in any introduction to HTTP (e.g. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Overview), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP#HTTP/1.1_response_messages)) an HTTP 1.x response consists of a *status line*, some *headers*, and then the *response body*. (HTTP/2 and HTTP/3 are not text-based protocols, so while all the same elements exist in the response, the way they're formatted is a bit more complex.)

So a really simple response would look like this, indicating a successful response, with a plain text body:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain

Hello, world!
```

The `Content-Disposition` line is just an extra header, which the browser uses as a hint for what to do next.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=TEST1234.txt

Hello, world!
```

Without knowing how you're currently trying to view the raw HTTP traffic, it's impossible to say why you're not seeing the full response. It looks like it's also mangled the quoting somewhere, unless `" ,"` is actually part of your suggested filename.

Comment: Okay thats a bit of a bother then essentually I have made a html server in vb.net which sends a html it compiles  together with the HTTP header to the cilent it works perfectly however I cant get it to actually work when its a download situation (as described above) it will however compile a file by the sugested name and even download it but the contents is always blank (empty) the file is simply empty not even blank spaces or invisible characters just empty... any sugestions what could be going on?

Comment: @LabRat Sounds like you need to post a new question with a [mre] of your vb.net code, so that someone knowledgeable in that language can point out what you've done wrong. A "download situation" should be literally adding that header line to the response *and not changing anything else* - the actual data to send is exactly the same, the header is just a hint to the browser about what to do *after* it receives it.